# Google Developer Console Not Showing Advanced Mode

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-developer-api

I want to Support different CPU architectures with each APK (such as for ARM, x86, and MIPS), but for that it seems I need the Advanced Mode, and its not visible in the section.

This is my first App in the Play Store, I don't know if this has anything to do with it.

Will appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

In the new Google play console, after uploaded a new APK, there is a button called "retain". you can click the "retain" button to keep 2 versions of APK.

Answer (score -2):

1. Login to you developer console ( Select your App )
2. Click on APK on left

[image]

3. Select ( Prod/Alpha/Beta). Upload your APK using button "Upload new Apk" button. Please not uploading apk here doesn't make it live immediately unless you publish app.
4. Once apk is uploaded ( Advance mode is visible on right)
   [image]
5. Refer to this link for specifying CPU architecture for each apk
   https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html#CpuArchOptions

   APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a mips

   APP_PLATFORM := android-9